# Flash programming causes unexpectedly reset

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, flash-memory

I'm working with a MCF51EM256 Freescale microcontroller and I've some problems with the flash programming.

In order to make my software persistant I'm trying to store some variables in the secondary flash memory to recover from unexpected shutdowns.

Sometimes, when I test my work shutting down the MCU, it is constantly reset.

I have to store this struct:

```
//  kWh or kVARh Energy accumulator type 
typedef struct {
    uint32 Ea_ps;   // Energy must be stored in kWh or kVARh
    uint32 Ea_ng;   // All fields must contain POSITIVE values!
    uint32 Er_q1;
    uint32 Er_q2;
    uint32 Er_q3;
    uint32 Er_q4;
}kWh_EnergyAcc32;
```

And these are my functions:

```
// This function stores in Flash a given kWh_EnergyAcc64 structure.  

void Save_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(long addr, kWh_EnergyAcc32* Acc) {

    // kWhEnergyAcc struct needs 32 bytes in Flash

    Flash_Burst(addr, 1, &(Acc->Ea_ps));
    Flash_Burst(addr + 4, 1, &(Acc->Ea_ng));
    Flash_Burst(addr + 8, 1, &(Acc->Er_q1));
    Flash_Burst(addr + 12, 1, &(Acc->Er_q2));
    Flash_Burst(addr + 16, 1, &(Acc->Er_q3));
    Flash_Burst(addr + 20, 1, &(Acc->Er_q4));

}
```

*

```
// This functions erase a flash sector in external flash

void EraseFlashSector(long startAddr) {

    // Sector size: 1 kB

    uint32 eraseData = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    Flash_Cmd((uint32)startAddr, (uint16)1, (uint32*)&eraseData, 0x40);
}
```

*

```
// This function initializes a given Ws_EnergyAcc64 structure with the
// stored values in Flash.

void Init_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(long addr, kWh_EnergyAcc32* Acc) {

    Acc->Ea_ps = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

    Acc->Ea_ng = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

    Acc->Er_q1 = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

    Acc->Er_q2 = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

    Acc->Er_q3 = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

    Acc->Er_q4 = *(uint32*)addr;
    addr = addr + 4;

}
```

*

And *flash programming* functions:

```
#define FLASH_MASS_ERASE_CMD  0x41
#define FLASH_ERASE_CMD       0x40
#define FLASH_PROGRAM_CMD     0x20
#define FLASH_BURST_CMD       0x25

#if (SYSTEM_CLOCK/2) > 12800000 /* 12.8 MHz */
    #define FLASH_CLOCK (UINT8)(( (SYSTEM_CLOCK/3200000) -1) | 0x40)
#else
    #define FLASH_CLOCK (unsigned char)( (SYSTEM_CLOCK/400000) -1)//<200KHz
#endif

/* Macros to call the function using the different features */
#define Flash_Burst(Address, Size, DataPtr) \
    Flash_Cmd((UINT32)Address, (UINT16)Size, (UINT32*)DataPtr, FLASH_BURST_CMD)

UINT8 /*far*/ 
Flash_Cmd(UINT32 FlashAddress, 
      UINT16 FlashDataCounter, 
      UINT32 *pFlashDataPtr, 
      UINT8 FlashCommand)
{
  /* Check to see if FACCERR or PVIOL is set */
  if (FSTAT &0x30)  
  {         
      /* Clear Flags if set*/
      FSTAT = 0x30;  
  }

  if (FlashDataCounter)
  {
    do
    {
        /* Wait for the Last Busrt Command to complete */
        while(!(FSTAT&FSTAT_FCBEF_MASK)){};/*wait until termination*/

        /* Write Data into Flash*/
        (*((volatile unsigned long *)(FlashAddress))) = *pFlashDataPtr;
        FlashAddress += 4;
        pFlashDataPtr++;

        /* Write Command */
        FCMD = FlashCommand;

        /* Put FCBEF at 1 */
        FSTAT = FSTAT_FCBEF_MASK;

        asm (NOP);
        asm (NOP);
        asm (NOP);

         /* Check if Flash Access Error or Protection Violation Error are Set */
        if (FSTAT&0x30)
        {     
          /* If so, finish the function returning 1 to indicate error */
          return (1);
        }

    }while (--FlashDataCounter);
  }
  /* wait for the last command to complete */
  while ((FSTAT&FSTAT_FCCF_MASK)==0){};/*wait until termination*/

  /* Return zero to indicate that the function executed OK */
  return (0);
}
```

My main program looks like:

```
static kWh_EnergyAcc32 PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr;
static long PhR_ABS_kWh_addr = 0x20000;

static long magic_word_addr = 0x20800;

main() {

    uint32 bad_magic_word = 0x12345678;
    uint32 ok_magic_word = 0x87654321;

    magic_word = *(uint32*)magic_word_addr;

    if (isFirstExecution() || (magic_word == bad_magic_word) || (magic_word == -1) {
        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        // Writes 0's in all addresses of the flash sector (1024 bytes)
        SetFlashSectorToZero(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);   
    }

    Init_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

    if (testIntegrity(PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr) == 0) {
        // Turn on LEDs to show a message
        ShowMsgLED(255, 0, 0);
    }

    while (1) {

        getValuesFromSensors(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        processValues(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        EraseFlashSector(magic_word_addr);
        Flash_Burst(magic_word_addr, 1, &bad_magic_word);

        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        Save_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        EraseFlashSector(magic_word_addr);
        Flash_Burst(magic_word_addr, 1, &ok_magic_word);

    }

}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Why my micro sometines is constantly reset when I turn off de power supply to test the persistance? There is a way to catch this fatal exception which causes the reset in my micro?

First I thought it might be caused by an error writing any flash address, during the shutdown, which after is not able to read properly but I tried to use a "magic word" written to a known location at the end of my flash write to check if the flash write had already finished and seems that was not the problem.

Edit: [MCF51EM256 Reference Manual](http://cache.nxp.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MCF51EM256RM.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation&fileExt=.pdf)

Edit 2: This is the memory map of my micro:

[image]

Edit 3:

I've included the FLASH_CLOCK definition in *Flash programming functions*

I've also included this function to check inconsistent values:

```
int testIntegrity(kWh_EnergyAcc32 Acc) {
    if (Acc.Ea_ps == -1 || Acc.Ea_ng == -1  || Acc.Er_q1 == -1 || Acc.Er_q2 == -1 || Acc.Er_q3 == -1 || Acc.Er_q4 == -1) 
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

Now, this function is called after initializing values and the leds never turn on.

Note: (Acc->Ea_ps == -1) is the same that (Acc->Ea_ps == 0xffffffff)

Edit 4:

The code for my function *SetFlashSectorToZero*:

```
void SetFlashSectorToZero(long addr){

    uint32 resetValue = 0x00000000;
    int endSector = addr + 1024;

    while (addr <= endSector) {

        Flash_Burst(addr, 1, &resetValue);
        addr = addr + 4;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your routines seem to doing things on the OnChip flash memory, not on an external device.

Comment: As far as I can understand your code is not taking care of the shutdown. What if the power supply disappears  while your code erased all the flash page? New Startup you'll have all values to `0xFFFFFFFF`. Is this managed by `processValues` function? Worse if write function is stopped during its execution...

Comment: Sorry @LP for the confusion. See the Edit 2. I'm trying to write the second flash array.

Comment: Little tip: you should disable interrupt during OnChip flash erase and write operations.

Comment: Yes @LP. First I've protected myself from using inconsistantly written values from flash with a "magic word" written to a known location at the end of my flash write and the problem persists. I did not include the code in the post.

Comment: Is that "magic word" inside the erased page address?

Comment: @LP obviously not. I'will include the pseudocode in an edit.

Comment: It must be there. To grants that the page erase could erase the "magic word". So, when a sanity check is performed and "magic word" is found, you are sure that the last erase/write operation completed its job. My nick is LPs not LP. SO cannot warn me if you write @LP.

Comment: @LPs sorry. Check my last edit.

Comment: I'll check. Is 2K the flash page size? If yes, as a little tip, you could use 0x207FC as address to stro the megic word. This allow you to avoid 3 page erase, and erase the page once.

Comment: On manual I found _(128 sectors of 1024 bytes each)_. You should use 0x203FC to store magic word.

Comment: Your startup sanity check should add (magic_word == `0xFFFFFFFF`), to check the case of flash erase on page 0x20800 was performed but not the write operation.

Comment: BTW add a disable interrupt before flash operation and re enable them at the end.

Comment: Note that the flash programming code has to reside in flash array 1 if you are programming flash array 2 or vice versa. Otherwise you might experience some very weird behavior. Another reason for sudden reset could be incorrectly configured flash pre-scaler clock. Where do you set that one up? On Freescale MCUs it is usually called FCLKDIV. You also need to check that register for errors before doing anything.

Comment: @Lundin check my 3th edit. I've added my flash clock definition. And I suppose that my flash programming code reside in flash array 1, like all the other code.

Comment: @LPs I cannot disable interrupts because my software need it, and throws an exception when I do it.

Comment: As far as your interrupts do not access the data block, you can avoid to disable interrupts. Take a look at [this application note](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN4695.pdf).

Comment: Could you post `SetFlashSectorToZero` code?

Comment: @LPs posted. Thanks for the doc. I'm reading it.

Comment: Your `SetFlashSectorToZero` function is bugged. If It is called because if `magic_word == bad_magic_word` the sector is not erased and you cannot reset the it to 0. Maybe this is tour real problem.

Comment: Take also note that Flash_Burst can be called with second parameter more that 1.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I just did not include the line EraseFlashSector in the post, but it was in my code. @LPs

Comment: `(addr <= endSector)` --> should be `(addr < endSector)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you solved your problem with our suggestions, but I think your code could be smaller in the following way:

```
static kWh_EnergyAcc32 PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr;
static long PhR_ABS_kWh_addr = 0x20000;

static long magic_word_addr = 0x203FC;

main() {

    uint32 ok_magic_word = 0x87654321;

    magic_word = *(uint32*)magic_word_addr;

    if (isFirstExecution() || (magic_word != ok_magic_word)) {
        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        // Writes 0's in all addresses of the flash sector (1024 bytes)
        SetFlashSectorToZero(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
    }

    Init_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

    if (testIntegrity(PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr) == 0) {
        // Turn on LEDs to show a message
        ShowMsgLED(255, 0, 0);
    }

    while (1) {

        getValuesFromSensors(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        processValues(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        Save_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        Flash_Burst(magic_word_addr, 1, &ok_magic_word);

    }

}
```

or

```
//  kWh or kVARh Energy accumulator type
typedef struct {
    uint32 Ea_ps;   // Energy must be stored in kWh or kVARh
    uint32 Ea_ng;   // All fields must contain POSITIVE values!
    uint32 Er_q1;
    uint32 Er_q2;
    uint32 Er_q3;
    uint32 Er_q4;
    uint32 magic_word;
}kWh_EnergyAcc32;

static kWh_EnergyAcc32 PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr;
static long PhR_ABS_kWh_addr = 0x20000;
static long *magic_word_addr = (uint32 *)(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr-sizeof(uint32));

#define OK_MAGIC_WORD 0x87654321

main() {

    if (isFirstExecution() || (*magic_word != OK_MAGIC_WORD)) {
        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        // Writes 0's in all addresses of the flash sector (1024 bytes)
        SetFlashSectorToZero(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
    }

    Init_Flash_kWhEnergyAcc(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

    if (testIntegrity(PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr) == 0) {
        // Turn on LEDs to show a message
        ShowMsgLED(255, 0, 0);
    }

    while (1) {

        getValuesFromSensors(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        processValues(&PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);

        PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr.magic_word = OK_MAGIC_WORD;
        EraseFlashSector(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr);
        Flash_Burst(PhR_ABS_kWh_addr, sizeof(kWh_EnergyAcc32)/4, &PhR_ABS_kWh_AccStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why.. but setting the magic_word_addr and  PhR_ABS_kWh_addr in the same flash sector and changing (addr <= endSector) --> by (addr < endSector) like u say I did not get more resets in my micro! Thanks @LPs

Comment: The key was `(addr < endSector)`. You was trying to write 4 bytes more than cancelled sector address space.

Comment: But I don't understand why. Previously (month ago) I tried to write a lot of flash addresses that were not erased, and never got those resets.

Answer (score 2):

- You cannot execute the flash programming code from the same flash array that is currently getting programmed. According to the manual for this specific device, it contains dual flash controllers just for the purpose of allowing you to program one flash array while programming the other.

  So you have to ensure that the flash programming code is allocated in a separate array. You might even need two complete duplicates of the flash programming code.

  Failing to do this will cause any random behavior.
- You have to configure the flash pre-scaler clock by writing to the FxCDIV register. An incorrectly configured flash clock will typically cause things like program hang-up or CPU reset. The clock needs to be within 150-200kHz. *Important*: you need margins, so have to take your clock inaccuracy in account, and also the inaccuracy that comes from your bus clock not being evenly divisible with whatever constant you picked.
- Needless to say, you cannot have any interrupts running during flash programming, in case they reside inside the flash array being programmed, or in case they try to access constants/call code inside that flash array.

Comment: It could be a good idea to move the flash programming code to RAM, so it can access both flash arrays. This avoids the need of two identical code blocks in each flash array. But copy to and execute from RAM is typically a bit tricky.

Comment: @jeb No, that's rarely ever a good idea, it is more of a dirty hack. I know that Freescale suggests this in various app notes, but it is not really a professional solution, it is rather a dirty work-around they invented after realizing the limitations of their own hardware. Running code from RAM is risky business. Also, RAM is usually more valuable than flash. Increasing the program size with a few hundred bytes shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can't see why it should be more risky than running from flash. And there are enough plattforms where it's the only solution to flash and partially able to handle interrupts while flashing. You are right, that RAM is valuable, but by copying the code to the stack it's for free.

Comment: @jeb Mainly because any bug will tear the whole program down, and possibly making it non-recoverable. But also because "op code arrays" are very fragile, and any program changes might invalidate everything. Historically there was also a worry about EMI when running code from RAM, but that's less of an issue nowadays (even though safety standards typically ban the practice of running code from RAM for that reason). Also note that you'd have to store the whole routine in flash anyhow, to copy it onto the stack when needed, so you are not really saving much memory at all.

Comment: @jeb Similarly, having large chunks of data on the stack, such as for example message buffers, is considered poor practice when writing mission-critical firmware. You open up more potential for stack overflow. Any stack-related bugs will crash the whole program. Any buffer overflow-related bugs will crash the whole program. And so on.

Comment: It's critical, when you store more program code on the stack, but the main flash programming code is typically small (~ 30-100 bytes) and it will be copied only when flashing is ongoing, so it's safe against spurious stack modifications from other software parts. And the code will be _removed_/freed from the stack after programming

Comment: Also some ABIs will not let you run code from data memory. I'm not sure if Coldfire allows it or not. Depends on the MMU.

Comment: It was "the only way to do a firmware upgrade" for Motorola 68K or some Freescale DSPs. ;) @jeb

Comment: @LPs I know :-)  I wrote a bootloader for a MC56F8006 (16KB Flash/2KB RAM) a mix of MCU and DSP. For crypted firmware

Comment: Thank you @Lundin. I'll be careful with the flash programming following your advices, but finally I did not get more resets in my micro setting the magic_word_addr and PhR_ABS_kWh_addr in the same flash sector and changing (addr <= endSector) --> by (addr < endSector)